# Adding an object to PHP array, before adding from MySQL select

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a PHP page encoding a MySQL select into JSON.
I would like to add a "Status value" as the first object of my array.

PHP code

```
{
//CREATE USER UNKNOWN ARRAY RESULT
$Statusresult = mysql_query("SELECT TEXT_KEY, TEXT_VALUE FROM T_TEXTS WHERE TEXT_KEY = 'USER_FAILED' ") or die(mysql_error());
$Statusrows = array();
while($s = mysql_fetch_assoc($Statusresult)) 
{
    $Statusrows[] = $s;
}
print json_encode($Statusrows);
```

}

This results is:

```
{
"TEXT_KEY" = "USER_FAILED";
"TEXT_VALUE" = "UNKNOWN USER";
```

}

I would like to add the first object manual, to have the result look like this:

```
        {
    "STATUS" = "1";
    "TEXT_KEY" = "USER_FAILED";
    "TEXT_VALUE" = "UNKNOWN USER";
}
```

How can I do this ?

I have tried this approach, but somehow there is an error...

```
{
    //CREATE USER UNKNOWN ARRAY RESULT
    $Statusresult = mysql_query("SELECT TEXT_KEY, TEXT_VALUE FROM T_TEXTS WHERE TEXT_KEY = 'USER_FAILED' ") or die(mysql_error());
    $Statusrows = array();
    $Statusrows = { "STATUS" => "1" };
    while($s = mysql_fetch_assoc($Statusresult)) 
    {
    //  $Statusrows[] = $s;
        array_push($Statusrows, $s);    
    }
    print json_encode($Statusrows);
}
```

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a ***virtual column*** on it,

```
SELECT '"1"' AS `STATUS`, TEXT_KEY, TEXT_VALUE 
FROM T_TEXTS 
WHERE TEXT_KEY = 'USER_FAILED'
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f52dc/5)

Comment: I tried this, but the result is somehow different...Missing the " around 1 and status

Comment: Adding a zero element before the SQL would be exact my approach - im just not sure how to do this i tried a few solutions, without any luck...

Comment: @UlrikVadstrup **SELECT '"1"' AS `STATUS`, ...** see my updated answer.

Comment: hmnn....It looks find when watching it in explorer [{"STATUS":"1","TEXT_KEY":"USER_FAILED","TEXT_VALUE":"UNKNOWN USER"}] but somehowe when decoding in Xcode, the " dissapers around the first object...{
        STATUS = 1;
        "TEXT_KEY" = "USER_FAILED";
        "TEXT_VALUE" = "UNKNOWN USER";
    }

Comment: Problem found - wrong coding in xcode - Thanks a million John Woo :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [array union operator (`+`)<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

```
$Statusrows[] = ["STATUS" => "1"] + $s;
```

Or:

```
$status1 = ["STATUS" => "1"];
while ($s = mysql_fetch_assoc($Statusresult)) 
{
    $Statusrows[] = $status1 + $s;
}
```

This would spare you to deal with that logic inside the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
$Statusrows = array();
while($s = mysql_fetch_assoc($Statusresult)) 
{
    $s["STATUS"] = "1";
    $Statusrows[] = $s;
}
```